# Handle 1 message from the queue at each turn

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I need to pull each message, handle it and once I've finished pull and next, because I'm sending many message to the queue, and I have few receivers, but I want each receiver to accept one message, process it, and pull the next.

I can't understand how to achieve this with this code:

```
def main():
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('admin', 'admin')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=ConfigurationManager.ConfigurationManager().getMessageBrokerUrl(), credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue=matchingExec.getChannelName(), durable=True)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    matchingExec.handleMatchingMessage(json.loads(body))

channel.basic_qos(1)    
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue=matchingExec.getChannelName(),
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
```

Comment: What is the problem with this?

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing what is the problem as you do not describe it in your question, one thing that is definitely odd is how you set your qos.

Does your problem go away if you do it like this:

```
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
```

Now you just set it as 1 without the keyword argument and according to documentation, the first parameter might be prefetch_size instead of prefetch_count.

But I am not 100% sure you can do this without message acknowledgements. As you are running it as `no_ack=True`, rabbit implicitly acknowledges every message as soon as they are sent to clients, and the server cannot tell if a message has already been processed by a client or not. This might nullify whatever effect basic_qos should in theory have, as the server does not receive any feedback from clients.

If it still does not work, try switching message acknowledgements on and acknowledging messages in your callback after finished processing.